# Обращение к php скрипту?

Tags: php, сервер, curl

Вообщем есть file.php, к которому я предоставляю доступ по api запросам. В запросе передается также специальный ключ, который проверяется и в случае чего пользователю дается ответ. Мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы еще и проверялся и адрес с которого перешли, так как юзеры делают запрос со своих хостов. Я посмотрел в сторону реферера, но его можно спокойно подменить через curl. Как это лучше и всего реализовать, и вообще возможно ли это. Благодарю за ответ заранее. Также извиняюсь если вопрос показался глупым, но мне на ум ничего не пришло

Comment: Эээ... а зачем используется ключ? Чтобы разграничить пользователей логично использовать именно его и не смотреть на хост. `Я посмотрел в сторону реферера` - ну так используйте IP адрес откуда пришел запрос, хотя ключ решает проблему, а IP адрес решает и создает новую.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но вся проблема в том и  заключатеся: предпожем что есть один ключ, юзер делает запросы, но тогда с этим же ключом запросы может слать и другой юзер, посмотрю в сторону ip

Comment: Откуда у другого юзера тот же ключ?

Comment: Предположем он поделился, вот собственно поэтому я и задал такой вопрос

Comment: Тогда вы хотите решить немного другую проблему - как решить проблему шаренья ключей API между пользователями. На этот счет есть такие решения: 1) выставка лимитов запросов => клиенты сами не захотят 2) прибивать IP адресы к клиентам, смена IP - по заявке в поддержку.

Comment: Спасибо, пожалуй на ip адресах и остановлюсь

Comment: Проблема с IP - на одном сервере, например шаред-хостине могут быть сотни и тысячи пользователей. Конечно совпадение минимальное, но такая проблема в общем-то есть.